# Is categorical encoding a type of word embedding?

Tags: comparison, terminology, word-embedding, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

Word embedding refers to the techniques in which a word is represented by a vector. There are also *integer encoding* and *one-hot encoding*, which I will collectively call [*categorical encoding*](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/categorical-encoding).

I can see no fundamental difference between the categorical encoding and word embedding at a fundamental level. They may be different at an application level.

Is it true that categorical encoding is a type of word embedding? And are different names solely due to the task in which apply the technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[One-hot encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/) is different than the concept of a word embedding, although both approaches use vectors to represent the objects (e.g. words).

A **one-hot vector** contains one element that is 1 and all other elements are 0. So, for example, the vector $[0, 0, 1, 0]$ is a one-hot vector, while the vector $[0, 2, 0.2, 0]$ is not. (Given that the sum of all elements in the one-hot vector is equal to 1 and all elements are in the range $[0, 1]$, a one-hot vector is a [probability vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_vector), although this may be irrelevant.) To represent your objects as one-hot vectors, you first need to know how many objects you have (in the context of NLP, this is often the *vocabulary size*). Let's say you have $N$ distinct elements
(e.g. words), then, in order for two objects not to be mapped to the same one-hot vector, you need to have one-hot vectors of $N$ dimensions. So, if $N$ is very large, this can be a disadvantage of one-hot encoding, although, in principle, you only need to store the index of the $1$ for each one-hot vector.

As opposed to one-hot vectors, which do not encode the meaning of the objects they represent, **word embeddings** *semantically* represent the objects, i.e. similar objects (for some notion of similarity) are typically mapped to similar word embeddings. Here's a picture that illustrates this concept (taken from the book that I cite below).

[image]

Moreover, word embeddings can easily be smaller than one-hot vectors and do not necessarily contain only 0s and 1s. More importantly, word embeddings are derived from data (often learned).

A similar argument can be said for integer encoding, i.e. they are not learned from data and they do not carry any meaning. [Chapter 6](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/ed3book.pdf#page=104) of [this book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/ed3book.pdf) discusses word embeddings more in detail.

To conclude, the common definition of a word embedding usually implies that word embeddings semantically represent objects and are derived/learned from data, so, generally, one-hot encoding is not a form of word embedding, but it's a way to [embed objects into a vector space](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/20646/2444).