# Is label-embedding similar to one-hot encoding?

Tags: terminology, papers, one-hot-encoding

In [one-hot encoding](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28097/18758), a vector is given to each class label. For each class, only one entry of the vector is equal to 1 and the remaining entries are zeros in this encoding.

Thus, in one-hot encoding, we are encoding the class label.

Is it true that [label-embedding](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08677.pdf) gives a vector for each class label like in one-hot encoding? Is one-hot encoding a type of label-embedding?